# Symfony Authenticate with UserProviderInterface without login when cookie present

Tags: symfony

I am using ldap authentication with a custom user provider.  If a user comes to my site with a cookie from another site on my domain I want to log them in automatically.  I was hoping I could use my UserProviderInterface from my login controller to do this but can't seem to figure out how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've been doing some looking and it seems like I need to be looking at the SimplePreAuthenticatorInterface.  Does this seem like the correct approach?

Comment: If "_another site_" was managed in the same app and have a configured firewall in `security.yml` could be enough to share the same [firewall-context](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#firewall-context) to have the user auto logged on both.

Comment: What have you tried? How did you try and use your UserProviderInterface? What didnt work, what if any errors were you getting?

Comment: I used a guard authenticator and it just worked.  I'll post the details of my solution below.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found this article:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html

the long and short of it is...

I added a new service in services.yml

```
app.cookie_auth:
    class: AppBundle\Security\CookieAuth
```

I added that service to my security/firewall/main in security.yml

```
  guard:
     authenticators:
       - app.cookie_auth
```

Then I created a new class // src/AppBundle/Security/CookieAuth.php
    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {

```
    if($_COOKIE["HelloWorld"] == "HelloWorld") {
        return array("token" => $_COOKIE["HelloWorld"]);
    }
  ...
public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
{
    $cookie = $credentials['token'];

    // if null, authentication will fail
    // if a User object, checkCredentials() is called
    return $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($cookie);
}
```

Everything just worked.